# DC.JS table Is it possible to hide a column?

Tags: dc.js

When using the dc.js table chart, I need a hidden column for sorting purposes, but do not know how to hide it from the user's view.

Answer (score 1):

solved using CSS and jquery

```
var columnindex = $('#dcTable th:contains("NameOfColumnToHide")').index();
if(columnindex != -1)
   $('#dcTable tr > *:nth-child('+(++columnindex)+')').hide();
```